# Xpages, dijit.form.RadioButton how to save value?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dojo, xpages, lotus

I plan to use [dijit.form.radiobutton](/questions/tagged/dijit.form.radiobutton) on a [xpage](/questions/tagged/xpage). I try to find a solution without using the [xpages-extlib](/questions/tagged/xpages-extlib).
If I add the [dijit.form.radiobutton](/questions/tagged/dijit.form.radiobutton) to the [xpage](/questions/tagged/xpage), the value of the button is not saved.

### Not working code

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="tstRadio"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.form.RadioButton"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:radio text="Yes" id="radio1" groupName="radio" selectedValue="yes" value="#{document1.radio}" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton">
        <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="name" value="radio"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="value" value="yes"></xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    </xp:radio>
    <xp:radio text="No" id="radio2" groupName="radio" selectedValue="no" value="#{document1.radio}" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton">
        <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="name" value="radio"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="value" value="no"></xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    </xp:radio>
</xp:view>
```

---

### Working code

Without the [dijit.form.radiobutton](/questions/tagged/dijit.form.radiobutton) the value saved properly.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:this.data>
<xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="tstRadio"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.resources>
       <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.form.RadioButton"></xp:dojoModule>
   </xp:this.resources>
   <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
       <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
           refreshMode="complete">
           <xp:this.action>
              <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
           </xp:this.action>
       </xp:eventHandler>
   </xp:button>
   <xp:radio text="Yes" id="radio1" groupName="radio" selectedValue="yes" value="#{document1.radio}">
       <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
           <xp:dojoAttribute name="name" value="radio"></xp:dojoAttribute>
           <xp:dojoAttribute name="value" value="yes"></xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    </xp:radio>
    <xp:radio text="No" id="radio2" groupName="radio" selectedValue="no" value="#{document1.radio}">
       <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
           <xp:dojoAttribute name="name" value="radio"></xp:dojoAttribute>
           <xp:dojoAttribute name="value" value="no"></xp:dojoAttribute>
       </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
   </xp:radio>
</xp:view>
```

---

### Question

I am not sure that the Not working code I wrote in the first example is correct, something may be missing from it. Is it possible to use dijit.form.Radio with working saving functionality on an Xpage ? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your first code snippet is not working because of this `<xp:dojoAttribute name="name" value="radio"></xp:dojoAttribute>`. This statement sets the `name` attribute of `input` tag to `radio` rather than something like this `view:_id1:radio`. I removed the line it was working for me. You also don't need to add `<xp:dojoAttribute name="value" value="yes"></xp:dojoAttribute>` as `selectedValue` does the job for you.

So you code becomes something like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="tstRadio"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.form.RadioButton"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:radio text="Yes" id="radio1" groupName="radio" selectedValue="yes" value="#{document1.radio}" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton">
    </xp:radio>
    <xp:radio text="No" id="radio2" groupName="radio" selectedValue="no" value="#{document1.radio}" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton">
    </xp:radio>
</xp:view>
```